# Spacing after comma when returning jquery result

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name=activeWarnings]').on('change', function() {
    $('#Warnings').val($('input[name=activeWarnings]:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get());
  });
});
```

The results output like one,two,three etc... i would like one, two, three with the spacing. I am using jquery.

Thanks

Comment: `return this.value+' ';` does not work?

Comment: @AlexOdenthal That would return something like `"one ,two, three, four "`. You could probably put the space before the value and use `.trim()`, but I'd personally prefer Satpal's `.join()` solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are currently passing an Array to `val()` function its convert to string literal internally.

You can use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get the desired string literal.

```
var arr = $('input[name=activeWarnings]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
$('#Warnings').val(arr.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace()`

```
var thisValue = "1,2,3,4,5";
alert(thisValue.replace(/,/gi,', '));
```

Where regex `/,/gi` will be replace commas for comma+space

Answer (score 0):

You need    `replace()`
here is your answer

https://jsfiddle.net/q0eakjmg/3/